# Отправка формы по submit

Tags: html, submit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть в данной ситуации? Есть 3 кнопки submit (move,delete,search). Как отследить по отдельности когда нажата delete когда move и тд. На данный момент получается если вбиваю что то в поиск и жму энтер в POST попадают значения всех 3-ех кнопок.

Comment: А зачем они все «submit»? Или зачем они все в одной форме?

Comment: Об  этом не подумал если чесно. То есть поиск можно обернуть в одну форму,остальные в другую?

Comment: Конечно можно. И, видимо, даже нужно.

Comment: П-проектирование. Самый важный этап разработки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте всем кнопкам одинаковое имя (`name`), но разные значения (`value`). На сервер будет передано значение, ассоциированное с нажатой кнопкой.

Пример:

1. HTML (клиентская сторона):

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Move To" />
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
   ```
2. PHP (серверная сторона):

   ```
   if ($_POST['action'] == 'Move To')
   {
       // ...
   }
   else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Delete')
   {
       // ...
   }
   else
   {
       // Защита от (вероятно злонамеренно) некорректного значения
   }
   ```

Comment: php не указан в вопросе

Comment: А как тогда обрабатывается форма? JavaScript-ом? Тогда на каждую кнопку можно назначить свой обработчик `onclick`.